# How to Refresh a page in JavaScript and redirect to controller's Action method with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, client-side-scripting

I have been trying in JavaScript to reload a page to particular controller's action method with a parameter but getting error.

My output works when I use

```
function fnReload(){
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

But I want to redirect to controller's action method with PARAM's value and I am trying this

```
 function fnReload(){
    // Gives me the value in a function
    var supId = data.supplierId;
    //redirects the page so the I can see the updated the data
    window.location.reload= '@Url.Action("GetSupplier", "Supplier", new { supplierId = supId })';
}
```

But it is also not working for me since it give me the error and on applying breakpoint on server side it doesn't go over there.

Can some one guide me what should I do reload the page and redirect to controller's action method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `trying in JavaScript to reload a page to particular controller's action method with a parameter but getting error` What's the error? And can you share the relevant code of your action method?

Comment: Well @FeiHan there is no error . Only the issue is whole application routing works in JavaScript. The only solution I have is window.location.reload but it redirects me to homepage but I want to be on the page where records got Added/ Updated.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = '/Supplier/GetSupplier?supplierId=' + supId;` to redirect to new page?

Comment: Well I have tried the following   window.location.href = '/Supplier/GetSupplier?supplierId=' + supId
            window.location.reload = '/Supplier/GetSupplier?supplierId=' + supId   and both of them is not reloading the page.

Comment: Are you sure that `fnReload` function is executed? Besides, you can check if browser does help make another request to `GetSupplier` endpoint in Network tab and what the actual response status is.

Comment: Yes it is getting executed since I have placed an alert('clicked'); placed and I had breakpoint on on controller's Action method.

Comment: Does it hit the breakpoint within controller action now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX call for this

```
// AJAX call
$.ajax({
    url: "GetSupplier",
    type: "get",
    data: { 
        supplierId: supId,
    },
    success: function(result) {
        result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(result);
        window.location = "/GetSupplier";
    },
    error: function(result) {
        result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . The issue is something the like reload is important just bcoz whole web application is made in such a way that where refreshing doesn't happen. I am not able to see the updated records. Calling AJAX wont help me since Record is added in DB and I can see the count all but on typing the supplier name doesn't come for that I need to window.location.reload but it takes me to the homepage. But I want to stay on the same page with the supplier id after windows.location.reload